# Error in Deploying the java(swing, oracle) project on client machin... java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleDriver

Tags: java, oracle, swing, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have use oracle 10g database and jdk 1.5 .
I'm using eclipse.
I have exported the project in `.jar` file (file is ok).

When I run jar file on client machine then I get

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:oracl.jdbc.driver.OracleDri.....
```

I have imported my database on client machine.

My connection code is :

```
  public void register(){
        try
          {
           // load oracle driver
          Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
          // connect using Thin driver
         con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","forbesmarshall","mukeshsir");

         //t1.setText("Connected");
          //con.close();
          }
          catch(Exception ex)
          {
     //         String lo= ex.toString();
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(m, ex.toString(),             "Incorrect value", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                ex.printStackTrace();
          }
    }
```

Comment: *"i have import my database on client machine"*  How exactly did you do that?  Do you understand this all comes down to the 'run-time class path'?

Comment: Client machine creates a db connection on to oracle on server?

Comment: 1st i have install oracle 10g on client machine and then use imp database_name/pass fromuser=username touser=username file=new_backup.dmp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey guys thanks for your reply and helpful suggestion , I got the answer it is related to jar creation and some code problem.. i m making it directly jar and its wrong we need to create Runnable jar.. and to load driver we need to use following code..

```
      try {
      //Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
     DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
      }catch(Exception ex){
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(m, ex.toString(),"Incorrect value", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          ex.printStackTrace();

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you defined your class path correctly? Which IDE you used to develop the project? 
I recommend to check
1. jdbc class path
2. Permission issue on directory
3. Sometime there might be a problem of java version.

Comment: Thanks Vishrut shah , I m using eclipse, and i have set class path as folliwing please help me yar ...classpath
.;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;D:\My Development\Practice\src\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar

path
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN;D:\My Development\Practice\src\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar

Answer (score 0):

You should import `import oracle.jdbc.*;` and set class path pointing to `ojdbc6.jar`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like oracle driver is not in your classpath you you misspelled driver class name in your code.  Error message in your question has incorrect package name: `oracl.jdbc.driver.OracleDri.....`, but package name in code sample is correct: `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`.  Also, you mentioned that you build JAR file from your sources.  Make sure that when you run your application, your claspath contains not only this JAR, but also all other JARs your application depends on including Oracle JDBC Driver JAR file.

Modern versions of Oracle JDBC driver do not require you to do `Calss.forName` at all, by using Service Provider mechanism.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail , i have set a path as followes               classpath
.;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\jdbc\lib\ojdbc14.jar;D:\My Development\Practice\src\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar

path
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_14\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\BIN;D:\My Development\Practice\src\PDFBox-0.7.3.jar  is there any changes i need to do in path or classpath , or anything in code, please help me frnd, i need it very urgently ,

Comment: @saisagar Do you have file `oracle/jdbc/driver/OracleDriver.class` in your `ojdbc14.jar`?  To check this you can rename `ojdbc14.jar` to `ojdbc14.zip` and browse it as normal ZIP archive.

Comment: @saisagar Are you starting your program by passing `-jar` option to JVM?  Could you please show command line you use to start your program?

Answer (score 0):

You need to place oracle jdbc jar "ojdbc6.jar" and your problem will resolve.

Comment: it shld be in your classpath but as i can see in your comment to other posts, you have ojdbc14 in your classpath. So this error should not come. Can you post your complete code which we can run.

Comment: Thanks for u r reply , i have already set but it doesn't work, please check my above connection code is that correct or wrong..